# Dragging a div containing form controls

Tags: jquery

I am using a div which contain check box, textbox and dropdown. I am using jquery draggable/droppable. When the div is dragged and dropped,  the values which i entered in the textbox, selection made in the dropdown etc are not retained. I used the clone of the draggable div, this retains teh textbox value and xhexk box option but not the dropdown selection. Can someone please help.

Comment: you can store the values in variables. after they drop it set the values to what they were.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and copy the value in the dropdown when it is selected using javascript.

When the box gets dragged, you can then input the value in it.

```
function dragged(){
    $(this).children('#dropdown').val(copiedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-replace-the-position/) link where the **Drag&Drop** are discussed more and resolved with an answer and also more Question with Answers. Take a look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EpxHE/13/) where the working sample avail. Hope, this might help you.

```
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        var $newDiv = $("<div class='dragdiv'>" + i +"<input type='textbox' value="+i+" /></div>");
        $newDiv.draggable({
                snap: '#droppable',
                snapMode: 'outer',
                revert: "invalid",
                cursor: "move",
                helper: "clone"
        }).droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    var $dragElem = $(ui.draggable).clone().replaceAll(this);
                    $(this).replaceAll(ui.draggable);
                }
        });

        $("#dragItems").append($newDiv);
    }
```